# openlayer 3 with geoserver

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I am trying my first application with openlayers3 and geoserver. The code in the bottom of this message is not working. I know that geoserver is working properly because when I run the following link I can see the image represented by Img_Sample in it.

So what's wrong with the openlayers code?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

thanks

JJ

**Link**
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Img_Sample&styles=&bbox=-130.85168,20.7052,-62.0054,54.1141&width=768&height=372&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "localhost:8081/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'Img_Sample'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code uses OpenLayers 2.13, not 3.X. Sure you included the right file?

Comment: Also, your localhost link won't work for anybody here, just you.

Comment: Thank you guys. I figured out the problem. Very simple. I was missing the http:/ . Once I added it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike openlayers2 ,openlayers3.x and above has 'ol' as top level namespace. 
Openlayers syntax has been changed from 3.x and above. 
Following is the documentation url for latest openlayers http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/